# Is there a way to change forms AllowEdits property from a module? VBA

Tags: forms, vba, module

I'm trying to change a forms AllowEdits property from a module in access. Currently I just have the code in every single form but am looking for a way to simply pass the form to a module where it will change the AllowEdits property to keep the form modules clean and easy.

Currently I have in my form:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    FormLocker.F9Unlocker myForm: Me.Form , KeyCode: KeyCode , Shift: Shift
End Sub
```

And in my module I have

```
Public Sub F9Unlocker(ByRef myForm As Form, ByRef KeyCode As Integer, ByRef Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 120 Then
    If myForm.AllowEdits = False Then
        myForm.AllowEdits = True
        myForm.AllowAdditions = True
        myForm.AllowDeletions = True
    Else
        myForm.AllowAdditions = False
        myForm.AllowEdits = False
        myForm.AllowDeletions = False
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Currently it keeps giving me type mismatch errors, and at this point I'm not even sure if it's possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: AllowEdits is on arange..  Isn't it?  For a form you probably want myForm.Enabled = False

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm very new to VBA and access but am learning quickly. Basically my client wants to be able to press F9 and unlock a form, fallowing the data to be edited. Previously I was doing it straight from the form but I got a little ambitious and was wondering if I could do it from a module. I'm looking to be able to turn on and off editing on a record basis, and when records change to lock it again. I had it working 100% without using a access-wide module.